# Calculating the angle between two vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I want to ask a question about the angle between two vectors.

I am a Chemistry student who is studying the bond angle between 2 Hydrogen atoms using Python.

I recall from final-year high school the following property of angles is observed between vectors:

$$\cos \theta = \frac{a\cdot b}{|a||b|}$$

and have been given the following three dimensional vectors in cartesian form:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.102249] (Sulfur)
[0.0, 0.968059, -0.817992] (Hydrogen 1)
[0.0, -0.968059, -0.817992] (Hydrogen 2)
```

A diagram is supplied below.

[image: Diagram representing vectors of concern]

I know the vectors of concern are `Hydrogen 1` and `Hydrogen 2`.

I know to take their dot product to calculate the ${a\cdot b}$ term of the fraction.

However, I have been asked to make use of numpy's `norm()` function, which returns a vector or matrix form.

From what I seem to make out, a vector norm in this instance is apparently the same as the length of the vector i.e. the modulus or $|a|$ of vector $a$ but I'm not sure if this is correct.

What does the norm of a vector serve as a purpose to the calculation of the angle between two vectors $a$ and $b$?

Comment: If you just take $a\cdot b$ you might get a value greater than $1$ or less than $-1$, an impossible value for the cosine.  The dot product gives the cosine if both vectors have length $1$.

Comment: @saulspatz that's fine but I'm just wondering about the purpose of the norm of the vector in this context as i've been asked to use it?

Comment: $\frac{a}{|a|}$ is a vector of length $1$ in the same direction as $a$.

Comment: @vik1245 `norm(a)` means $|a|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) is just the [magnitude or modulus or whatever you call it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(mathematics)#Euclidean_vector_space), this code should do the trick:

```
from numpy import arccos, array
from numpy.linalg import norm

# Note: returns angle in radians
def theta(v, w): return arccos(v.dot(w)/(norm(v)*norm(w)))

sulfur = array([0.0, 0.0, 0.102249])
hydrogen_1 = array([0.0, 0.968059, -0.817992])
hydrogen_2 = array([0.0, -0.968059, -0.817992])
print(theta(hydrogen_1-sulfur, hydrogen_2-sulfur))
```

The numpy function is documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html).

Comment: Fabulous! I wrote a similar block of code using `numpy` so I'm guessing from what I see that the norm of the vector is as I've said like the modulus itself?

Comment: @vik1245 Yes. It'd be understandable if you also thought it might be the squared length instead. Even I sometimes either look it up or try `norm([3, 4])` to be sure it gives $5$.